# Loop Function required

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Hi I am using a slideToggle function on clickng an image.
Suppose there are four images in my page,If I click on particular image its must show a particular content related to image.At present I got that by using the below mentioned script which i declared separately for each image. But I need to include some 100 images in my page with same functionality I can't repeat the function 100 times which is  not a good practise. So can anyone help me how can I get this using a single loop without repeating the function.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".img").click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
            $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('off')) {
            $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        }
        $(function() {
            $(".hide-con").slideToggle("800");
        });

    });

            $(".img1").click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
            $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('off')) {
            $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        }
        $(function() {
            $(".hide-con1").slideToggle("800");
        });

    });

            $(".img2").click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
            $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('off')) {
            $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        }
        $(function() {
            $(".hide-con2").slideToggle("800");
        });

    });

            $(".img3").click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
            $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('off')) {
            $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        }
        $(function() {
            $(".hide-con3").slideToggle("800");
        });

    });

            $(".img4").click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
            $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('off')) {
            $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        }
        $(function() {
            $(".hide-con4").slideToggle("800");
        });

    });
        });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="img on"></div>
<div class="hide-con">
    <h1>Background</h1>
    <p><strong>Textile-India (T-India)</strong> is an Indian company engaged </p>
</div>  

<div class="img1 on"></div>
<div class="hide-con1">
    <h1>Background</h1>
    <p><strong>Textile-India (T-India)</strong> is an Indian company engaged </p>
</div>  

<div class="img2 on"></div>
<div class="hide-con2">
    <h1>Background</h1>
    <p><strong>Textile-India (T-India)</strong> is an Indian company engaged </p>
</div>  

<div class="img3 on"></div>
<div class="hide-con3">
    <h1>Background</h1>
    <p><strong>Textile-India (T-India)</strong> is an Indian company engaged </p>
</div>  

<div class="img4 on"></div>
<div class="hide-con4">
    <h1>Background</h1>
    <p><strong>Textile-India (T-India)</strong> is an Indian company engaged </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Give them the same class and establish a common markup structure which let's you reach the corresponding `.hide-con` through DOM traversal methods.

Comment: provide some HTML mark up..

Comment: give common class name for all images and add a single click event for all images pertaining to common class declared for all images :)

Comment: please add the HTML markup so we can help you using DOM Traversal [http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/]

Comment: I added HTML code also please check

Answer (score 1):

You should define only one class `img` and use your today's classes as id :

```
<img class=img id=img3 src=...>

$(".img").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('off')) {
        $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    }
    $(".hide-con"+this.id.slice(3)).slideToggle("800"); // extracts the number from the id
});
```

Note that I removed the useless `$.ready` wrapper.

You'd better also use `id=hide-con3` instead of `class=hide-con3` and use  `$("#hide-con"+this.id.slice(3))` to select it.

Comment: but when i use same class the slideToggle is opening for all other images also

Comment: `$(".hide-con3").slideToggle("800");` will toggle all the contexts, not only the one related to the clicked image.

Comment: I have changed my code accordingly but toggle is not working now

Answer (score 0):

try with attribute selector and `^` operator

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("img[class^='img']").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('off')) {
        $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    }

     //you don't have to wrap this in ready function again  
     $(".hide-con").slideToggle("800");
  });
});
```

this select all img with class begining with `img`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it with a `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var n = i == 0 ? '' : i;
    $(".img" + n).click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
            $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('off')) {
            $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        }
        (function (n) {
            $(function () {
                $(".hide-con" + n).slideToggle("800");
            });
        })(n);
    });
}
```

I recommend against this approach and go with a proper class-based solution as everyone is suggesting. The only challenge with a class-based solution is how to handle `.hide-con`, getting to it would depend on where it is positioned relative to the associated `.img`.

You may be wondering what's with this section:

```
(function (n) {
    $(function () {
        $(".hide-con" + n).slideToggle("800");
    });
})(n);
```

Without this wrapping function every `.img` click would call `slideToggle()` on `.hide-con100` because the value of `n` will be retained. To get around it we call an anonymous function and give it the value of `n`, inside the function now it is it's own variable so incrementing the outer one won't affect it.

Comment: Hi I have done the changes but only the 100th image content (i.e,hide-con100) is Toggling on clicking any of the image(i.e,img1 or img2 or img3)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(function() {
        $(".hide-con3").slideToggle("800");
});
```

with

```
$(this).slideToggle("800");
```

This will ensure only the selected instance toggles and not all of them and use a the same class on all images.